# Parsing ! in R regexes

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I'm trying to parse a former colleague's R code, and it's full of expressions like:

```
\bso\!so
```

What is the function of the exclamation point in this code? I suspect it has something to do with some kind of look(ahead|behind|around), but I don't know.

Comment: In regex, `\!` matches a literal `!` if not part of `(?!...)`  or `(?<!...)` lookaround constructs.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you explain this in a bit more detail? I looked at the other question you cited, and it does not really explain. Why does the expression include both "\bso" and "\b!so"? What is encompassed in a literal ("\b!so") that is not encompassed in a non-literal ("\bso") and why use them in conjunction?

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/1NZQbC/1. The linked question provides the link to many regex testers incl. regex101.com where all regexps are explained.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful. (Also, this tester is very powerful!)